# Why can't I set the padding of a link in such a way that it will hover fullscreen?

Tags: css

In my navigation bar, the links to other pages are placed underneath each other.

The links change by background-color when you hover them. Now I want it to hover full screen.

I already tried by setting `padding-left` and `padding-right:auto`, but that just doesn't work as I expect.

I don't want to add a fixed measurement(ex. `padding-left: 100px; padding-right:100px;`) because then it won't be responsive anymore when I minimize or enlarge the browser.

How can I do this?

Sorry I don't want it to hover fullscreen but to hover the size of the `<div>`.

**HTML:**

```css
<div id="website">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#wie">wie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#hoe">hoe</a></li>
            <li><a href="#wat">wat</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
body {
    font-size: 62.5%; /* 16px*62.5%=10px */
    font-family: Cabin, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    background-image: url(../images/ruitjesweb.svg);
}
#website {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
nav {
    background-color: white;
}
nav li {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav a:link, nav a:visited, nav a:hover, nav a:active {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    background-color: red;
}
nav a:hover {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Show us some code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: What do you mean, "hover full screen"?

Comment: maybe look into css: `calc()` function

Comment: not full screen but the size of the <div> where my links are situated in..

Comment: Show some code.. otherwise this is a matter of guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, all you need to do is add the [`display: block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) attribute to your `<a>` elements, e.g. like this:

```css
nav a:link, nav a:visited, nav a:hover, nav a:active {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;            /* <-- add this line */
}
```

This will cause the links to be rendered as [block-level elements](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements), which will, by default, take up the entire width of the `<li>` element containing them.

Here's [a demo of the result on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8UyL/).  In the demo, I also added `display: block` (instead of the default `display: list-item`) to the `<li>` elements to get rid of the bullets, and `padding: 0` to the `<ul>` to get rid of the indentation.  The result is that all these elements, down to the `<a>`s, inherit the full width of the enclosing `<div>`.

Comment: Yes that was the solution :) I've already figured it out on my own after some other unhelpful comments... But thank you for the solution!

Comment: No problem. If you found this answer useful, consider [marking it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check mark icon next to it, so that your question will be listed as answered. (Doing so will also give both of us a little bit of rep here on SO.)